# ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (35424, 0))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train the dataset using keras and tensorflow, the code runs fine till the model summary, after that I'm getting a value error. Here is my code for training the parameters:

```py
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])
print("[INFO] training network...")

history = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1
)
```

included my error message screenshot [image: here]

Comment: is this related(?):https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494896/what-is-the-meaning-of-rank-4-of-data-in-the-flow-method-of-imagedatagenerator

Comment: @Shayan Yes lit bit same, I solved my issue by running in jupyter notebook, pycharm is not flexible for data training. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Great! I think it's better to write the solution as answer; so people will be notice how you got rid of the error.